# Three.js MeshPhongMaterial is no longer "shiny" after a texture is applied

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rendering, render

If you look at the following codepen, you'll see a white, shiny "cup" which is a `.glb` that been loaded in using Three's GLTFLoader:

https://codepen.io/snakeo/pen/XWOoGPL

[image: screenshot]

However, when I apply a texture on a portion of the mug the shiny cup turns into a dull and spotty cup:

[image: dull]

You can apply the texture on the Codepen by uncommenting line 102:

```
// Create MeshPhongMaterial with the texture
const phongMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
   color: 0xFFFFFF,       // White color for the ceramic look
   shininess: 30,         // Adjust shininess for the ceramic effect
   specular: 0x222222,    // Specular color
   // map: texture           // Apply the texture
});
```

The image only appears on the "face" of the cup.

I'm not sure why this transformation occurs. I'm kind of new to this and hoping for some guidance.

Thank you.

I've tried changing `texture.wrapS`, `texture.wrapT` and `texture.repeat` with strange results, none of which cause the cup to be white and shiny again.

Comment: Tell me if you wish to see some code working around your model. I have already downloaded the model and the texture. If you don't know how to deal with something, add a comment and I will try to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MeshPhongMaterial is not that great once once working with shiny or glassy materials, yes it is lighter for the GPU but may never look as good as you want!

So, other options are avilable, like [MeshStandardMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial). This one is quite amazing and not that heavy on the performance.

Yet, if you only need that cup, or simply a single object, then you may use [MeshPhysicalMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhysicalMaterial). This one is way better with extra Clearcoat, Physically-based transparency, Advanced reflectivity, and Sheen.

Using textures on those material wont effect how shiny should they look like. If you really only want to use MeshPhongMaterial, *for some reason*, then [see this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=phong#webgpu_lights_phong). **Note:** you can check the code by opening the inspector or search for the name of the file if you have the Three.js GitHub repo downloaded, like (#webgpu_lights_phong) in the examples directory. **Note:** the codepen attached wasn't working for me for some reason, yet got what you meant and tried to help as much as I can!

#### Extra Useful Links

[Best physical material example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=physical#webgl_materials_physical_clearcoat)

[Transparency in the Physical material](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=physical#webgl_materials_physical_transmission_alpha)

[Using Physical Material in practice (YouTube)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DaJun0Q0CG_A&psig=AOvVaw0YyleD2V9nII2DKpnCU1NL&ust=1701946179660000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=2ahUKEwjFjv_c0fqCAxUMQaQEHfLaBPYQr4kDegQIARA6)

[Textures & Texture Mapping in Three.js (YouTube)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DthVl4UOQSEM&psig=AOvVaw0YyleD2V9nII2DKpnCU1NL&ust=1701946179660000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=2ahUKEwjFjv_c0fqCAxUMQaQEHfLaBPYQr4kDegQIARBQ)

Comment: Thank you so much Mohammed. I would love to pick your brain if you have some time to spare. Is there an email or messaging service where you can be reached?

Comment: "Note: the codepen attached wasn't working for me for some reason, yet got what you meant and tried to help as much as I can!" Codepen works you have to press button "Run"...

Comment: Thanks dear Łukasz D. Mastalerz. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you tried increasing `shininess` and `specular`, for example (`shininess: 100`, `specular: 0x444444`), but you are not satisfied.

Did you try MeshStandardMaterial:

```
const standardMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
         color: 0xFFFFFF,
         roughness: 0.4,
         metalness: 0.7,
         map: texture 
      });
```

But I assume that you need for some reason `MeshPhongMaterial`, so try this approach

```
const originalSpecularMap = mesh.material.specularMap;
const phongMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
         color: 0xFFFFFF,
         specularMap: originalSpecularMap,
         shininess: 60,
         map: texture,
         specular: 0x666666,
         emissive: 0x444444,
         emissiveIntensity: 0.6
      });
```

You can play with these values, I think you can easily get desired result.

Comment: Thanks so much Łukasz. This is very helpful. I actually don't *need* to use that material, it's my lack of knowledge in this domain that I thought it was necessary. Your comment is eye opening!